# Ubuntu 9.10 wireless problem 

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking

I have a gateway NV74 with AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) on Ubuntu 9.10. Wireless doesn't work that well, the connection is bad, and system disconnects itself often. Also, sometimes the machine crashes, and I have to reboot the computer. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install these two packages.

```
linux-backports-modules-karmic-generic.
linux-backports-modules-wireless-karmic-generic.
```

and you should take [this Wireless Trouble Shooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide). and Take a look at [WiFiHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo) and [WiFiCard Supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)